Drag and drop in WPF on .NET 8 / C# does not work - bug in framework?
I was working on another project and thought I was done until I tested the drag and drop capability (following a code example) and it failed to work as expected.
I created a simple WPF project on .NET 8 to test drag and drop, and it fails to work as well. Any know the secret to making this work?
Here is the MainWindow.xaml markup:
<Window x:Class="TestDragAndDrop.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TestDragAndDrop"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Grid>
        <TextBox x:Name="txtTextBox1" AllowDrop="True" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="201,236,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBox" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="319" DragOver="TextBox_DragOver" Drop="TextBox_Drop"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>

Here is the code behind MainWindow.xaml.cs:
using System.Text;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace TestDragAndDrop;

/// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void TextBox_DragOver(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Effects = DragDropEffects.All;
        e.Handled = true;
    }

    private void TextBox_Drop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.FileDrop))
        {
            string[] files = (string[])e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.FileDrop);

            if (files.Length > 0)
            {
                txtTextBox1.Text = files[0];
            }
        }
    }
}

I even asked the AI to do this, and it gave me similar code - same events, but the events do not actually fire. What is going on? Does .NET 8 not support drag & drop for WPF?
I'm at a loss.
This is easy to reproduce (I did it in the latest version of VS2022 17.10.3)

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32488786/wpf-dragover-event-is-not-firing-on-my-listbox

Good point in that link, but it's not a security issue, rather a bug in WPF .Net8 (maybe other versions).

Ok, I have a solution for this problem.
It's simple:
Replace all your _DragOver events with _PreviewDragOver
Replace all your _Drop events with _PreviewDrop
Apparently, DragOver & Drop events are not supported anymore (go figure).
Here is the MainWindow.xaml markup:
   <Window x:Class="TestDragAndDrop.MainWindow"
            xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
            xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
            xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
            xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
            xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TestDragAndDrop"
            mc:Ignorable="d"
            Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
        <Grid>
            <TextBox x:Name="TextBox" AllowDrop="True" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="201,236,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBox" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="319" PreviewDragEnter="TextBox_PreviewDragEnter" PreviewDragOver="TextBox_PreviewDragOver" PreviewDrop="TextBox_PreviewDrop" />
        </Grid>
    </Window>

And the corrected code behind w/ the correct events:
using System.Text;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace TestDragAndDrop;
/// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void TextBox_PreviewDragOver(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Effects = DragDropEffects.All;
        e.Handled = true;
    }

    private void TextBox_PreviewDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.FileDrop))
        {
            string[] files = (string[])e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.FileDrop);
            if (files.Length > 0)
            {
                TextBox.Text = files[0];
            }
        }
    }
}

I hope this helps others.

It is wrong that those events "are not supported anymore". See the duplicate question - this problem is specific to the default drop handling of the TextBox control.

It is also sufficient to use PreviewDragOver instead of DragOver, and renaming the handler methods is not actually necessary. So you could have written <TextBox ...  PreviewDragOver="TextBox_DragOver" Drop="TextBox_Drop"/>

If these events are NEVER fired, then they are clearly not supported or there is, yet, another bug in WPF.
If you actually read the question, then you would know that it is NOT a duplicate of that decade old link! READ\

Have you tested any other control than a TextBox? Have you actually read the accepted answer? See Update 2 in that answer.

What for?  Will you be dragging and dropping to a button?  a stack panel?  C'mon, REALLY? Their "accepted answer" has little to do with this - and their question is difficult for most people to follow (If you're using unmanaged code, you may not be able to port the code via Avalonia or even Mono).

I have added some more duplicates. The problem is well-known and all but a "new bug". You should understand that a TextBox already handles the PreviewDragOver event.
